# What does .CDB files represent in a java stacktrace?

Tags: java, stack-trace

It seems a bit naive to ask but I am really curious to know that what kind of source files are *.CDB?

For example,

```
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:236)
   at     com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.peer.acceptor.TcpAcceptor$TcpProcessor.onRead(TcpAcceptor.CDB:53)
    at   com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.peer.acceptor.TcpAcceptor$TcpProcessor.onSelect(TcpAcceptor.CDB:44)
   at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.peer.acceptor.TcpAcceptor$TcpProcessor.onNotify(TcpAcceptor.CDB:13)
   at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:42)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

You can see that all com.tangosol classes have line numbers against a *.CDB file while others end in *.java files.

Comment: *"Thanks,
Manish"*  Don't include sigs. in questions.

Comment: I came to know that tangosol or coherence libraries were written in some language other than Java which compiles to bytecodes. These source files would be ending with *.CDB.